# Problem with Arduino and INA226 power meter module

Tags: arduino-uno, power

I am new to the use of Arduino in general, and to the INA226 Module for power metering.

I first got everything set up WITHOUT anything plugged to the INA226 module metering pins (V+, ISens+, Isens-, V- not connected to any power source) and running a sample code that gets data being read by the INA226, of course, all values return 0, but at least I know the program runs and the arduino can connect to the INA226. Now, the problem comes when I try to get some reading such as 5V or even 3.3V from the Arduino pins.

I connected the circuit as follows:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fXJ65d.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

(I noticed that I wrote A6 instead of A4, sorry about that)

But when I do this, there is no reading at all from the serial console. I tried connecting the V+ and Isens+ directly to the 5V pin leaving everything else as shown in the diagram, but the Arduino board doesn't even turn on.

I tried referencing other sources, but their tests use external power supplies or other equipment I don't have.

I would be really thankful if someone could lend me a hand here or help me understand why am I having this problem and how can I make it read something basic such as 5V or 3.3V directly from the Arduino board.

Thanks!

Comment: I normally use 4.7K for the pull ups, don't know if that will make a difference

Comment: You need a shunt resistor between Isens+ and Isens- to get any meaningful readings. You also need a load between V+ and Isens+. The way you have it wired right now makes no sense.

Comment: @majenko Thank you very much for your reply. I tried getting the load from the Arduino board itself as I don't have many resources and I want to test this INA226 module. Also, as far as I know there is already a shunt resistor embedded into the Module, do I need an additional one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a discrepancy in pin terminology between your schematic & what TI uses in their datasheets. I don't see anything in their datasheets using I+ or I-. I only see V+ & V-. These 2 pins perform all your voltage & current measurements depending on the "mode" you tell the IC to use.

As near as I can tell based on your schematic, you should be seeing the voltage reading based on what is applied between V+ & V- (In your case, 3.3vdc) if you've told the chip to read the bus voltage channel.

You should also be getting a current reading between the V+ & V- pins if you've told the chip to read the shunt voltage channel. Since the part is designed for a full scale voltage differential of 36v between the V+ & V- pins, I suspect a reading of about 10% of max (based on a 3.3v differential).

I confess to not knowing the board or its operation but having looked it up on the TI website, it does appear to have a few jumper settings & a calibration routine to follow. There's a user guide on TI's website as well as the usual technical data pages. Perhaps those will assist in setting the jumpers correctly. [ina226 data sheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ina226.pdf) & [eval board user guide](http://www.ti.com/lit/ug/sbou113/sbou113.pdf)
bc

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed reply @user33722 . This module I'm using has some additional components such as the shunt resistor you mentioned I was missing, it's all integrated into it. Turns out it was just a simple wiring problem and now I got it working fine. 

For future reference, this is where more information can be found for this module and wiring https://strawberry-linux.com/pub/ina226-manual.pdf (Japanese)

Answer (score 1):

If this is the usual Arduino-style module with a shunt resistor already in it, then with your schematic, you have [nearly] shorted your supply rail. Your schematic should have the load wired in series to the `Isense+` and `Isense-` terminals, and the `V+` and `V-` terminals should be connected in parallel across the voltage powering the load.

The current must "pass through" the `Isense` terminals, and the module has to measure the voltage across the load in order to be able to get both I and V to compute power consumption.